# Trying to split an array in python

Tags: python, firebase

I am trying to split an array in multiple variables

This is how my Firebase document looks like

[image: How my database document looks like]
I am getting the information as such

```
response = requests.request("GET", API_ENDPOINT_GETCONNECTIONS_FIREBASE, headers=headers, data=payload)

sourceIp = str(json.loads(response.content)[0]['sourceIp'])
userHandle = str(json.loads(response.content)[0]['userHandle'])
destinationIp = str(json.loads(response.content)[0]['destinationIp'])
ports = str(json.loads(response.content)[0]['ports'])
print(response.content)
print(sourceIp)
print(destinationIp)
print(userHandle)
print(ports)
print(len(ports))
```

Is it possible that I can create variables like:
port1 = 80,
port2 = 443 and so on?

Also the array won't always only have two elements, the number would change depending on the request.

Comment: Not quite, even though logically len(ports) would be 2, mine returns 9. print(ports) returns [80, 443]

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  It appears to me that you need to do two things: (1) focus the problem to the piece you need to work on; the file format is immaterial, now that you have it successfully read in; (2) Work through Python tutorials on that data structure.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace those existing resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `ports` is not a list, it's a string that looks like a list: `'[80, 443]'`, which is why it has length 9.

Turn it into a list first, then you can access it normally:

```
ports = eval(ports)
print(ports[1])
print(ports[2])
```

Note that `eval()` tells Python to evaluate a string as if it were a bit of Python and return the value of that expression. This works in your case, but it's generally a risky strategy (no knowing what might be in there).

A better way in your case might be to parse it as JSON, using the `json` library.